# Lifetime of Excited states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, half-life

[image: Electron transition to first excited state in two molecules]

Which of the transitions will have a higher lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot make judgement about the lifetime of a state solely from its energy. One needs the strength of the interaction and the final density of states, as included in the Fermi golden rule. Note that the interaction strength will include both the properties of the system (such as the dipole moment) and the strength of the field provoking the transition (most likely temperature-dependent radiation fluctuations).